# Veeam | "Failed to check certificate expiration date" after certificate renewal

Tags: certificate, veeam

Since yesterday we receive the message "Failed to check certificate expiration date" on a Veeam server.

The certificate is correct. (Was yesterday renewed!)

[image]

(German: issued for, issued by, valid from, valid until)

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: For curiosity, did you renew the certificate manually or was that the automatic renewal?

Comment: @marsh-wiggle sorry, can't remeber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug (look: [Certificate expiration date](https://www.veeam.com/kb2806)). You have to manually renew the certificate, solution is here: [Generating Self-Signed Certificates](https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/backup/agents/agents_self_signed_ssl.html?ver=95)

Before doing this, check first if any backup job is running. Doing this while a backup job is running may terminate the job. Use it only when you're working with **self signed certificates**!

Quoting the solution:

> 1. From the main menu, select `General Options`.
> 2. Click the `Security` tab.
> 3. In the Security tab, click `Install`.
> 4. At the Certificate Type step of the wizard, select `Generate new certificate`.
> 5. At the Generate Certificate step of the wizard, specify a friendly name for the created self-signed TLS certificate.
> 6. At the Summary step of the wizard, review the certificate properties. Use the Copy to clipboard link to copy and save information about the generated TLS certificate. You will be able to use the copied information to verify the TLS certificate with the certificate thumbprint.
> 7. Click `Finish`. Veeam Backup & Replication will save the generated certificate in the Shared certificate store on the Veeam backup server.